# Bind different instances of a program to different Eth/Usb ports (Windows)

Tags: networking, windows-11, port, network-interface

For my job I connect a target system to my Win11 laptop via Ethernet cable, then analyze it with 2 proprietary programs. I often analyze multiple systems per day, so I'm looking for a way to do them in parallel.

The programs support multiple concurrent instances, and the PC can talk to many systems concurrently using many cables (with USB-Eth adapters).

Unfortunately the programs are designed so they expect only one system, so when multiple systems are connected only one shows up, the same in each instance of the programs.

**Can I restrict which interface(s) each instance of these programs can use, so I can control which system(s) each instance of the programs can see?**

I've been suggested to use multiple VMs, because VMs have interface assignment tools, but it's impractical, unreliable, inefficient.
(EDIT: I've also been suggested Docker but [it doesn't run Windows apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102389/how-do-you-run-an-exe-file-on-docker).)

Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: What about using multiple Docker machines?  I think this what they are for.

Comment: @John ty. I never heard about Docker, but 20s spent on reading [what it is](https://github.com/docker/machine) are promising. Do you know any noob friendly guide on it?

Comment: Here is a possible resource for you .   I have not used docker myself.    https://knowledgebase.aridhia.io/workspaces/analysing-data/virtual-machines/installing-software-on-virtual-machines/installing-docker-on-your-virtual-machine

Comment: I've discovered that Docker is not suited to run Windows apps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102389/how-do-you-run-an-exe-file-on-docker